# NGINX doesn't stop listening 80 port

Tags: http, nginx, https, rhel7

i want nginx to stop listen 80 port, and only listen https port

So I changed config file like this:

[image]

[image]

But its still listening http port
And result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, for whose having this problem i wanted to share.

In config file there is a line

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf

This line was causing to always listen port 80, i commented it out. And problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

That was my problem too!  I had labeled the default file as default.old... it was still being read. Had to rename it to ".default.old".  Once that was done, I restarted nginx. Port 80 was no longer listening, and 443 was still working correctly.

I did not have the "include" statement, but nginx will read everything in the config.d folder regardless.